# Failed: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'visible' since it isn't a known property of 'p-dialog'

Tags: angular-cli, karma-jasmine, primeng

I have used PrimeNG p-dialog. It works OK when running the program.  However, when I tried to test the program using "ng Test" (Karma).  I got this error:

Failed: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'visible' since it isn't a known property of 'p-dialog'.
1. If 'p-dialog' is an Angular component and it has 'visible' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-dialog' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("....

What seems to be reason why?

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell Angular you are working with custom/3rd party components.
To do so, add this:

```
schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
```

to your `beforeEach` part of component test.
Full `beforeEach` will look like this:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
   TestBed.configureTestingModule({
     declarations: [YourComponentDeclaration],
     schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
   }).compileComponents();

   fixture = TestBed.createComponent(YourComponentDeclaration);
   component = fixture.componentInstance;
   fixture.detectChanges();
}));
```